# Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher is recommended. When Deploying a ASP.NET website to amazon ec2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-ec2, microsoft-web-deploy

I followed [this](http://martinbuberl.com/blog/deploy-aspnet-mvc-on-amazon-ec2-with-web-deploy/) tutorial

I installed web deploy 3.5,and added the website in iis on ec2 instance im still getting this error .[image]

Im using public dns as the service url

Thanks in advance

Edit: im using visual studio 2012 and website is in .NET 4.5

Comment: was there any errors while installing ?

Comment: @utility no error everything went fine exactly like the tutorial each n every step except i changed the name of the website .  i also checked the web deployment service running in services.msc

Answer (score 0):

Install Web deploy 3.5 on your local machine too using WPI